# python string u"%(word)s"

Tags: python, string, syntax

I'm a new user of Python, and I don't know some parts when I read the code. So I asked here.

```
cmd = u"sudo umount %(mountpoint)s >>%(log)s 2>&1"
```

I know that `%(word)` is used to replace the word latter use such as `cmd % {'word':'new word'}`, but I don't down why there is a trailing `s`. and I don't know the 'u' meaning at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `u` means it is a unicode string.
2. `s` stands for string.

Answer (score 7):

The beginning `u` means "Unicode" (i.e. it's a Unicode string). The `s` after each formatting code means to interpret the value as a string, as opposed to `d` for decimal, etc.

See the documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations for all the details.

Answer (score 3):

The u at the beginning of the string means that it's a unicode string.

The trailing s means that that part of the formatting should be a string. If it was a a d it would be an integer, and if it was an f it would be a float

Answer (score 1):

`s` is a conversion specifier, meaning print it as a string.

See [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), point 3:

> Conversion flags (optional), which affect the result of some conversion types.

The leading `u` means it is a `unicode` object, not a `str`.

See [Unicode in Python, Completely Demystified](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) for a great overview of the difference between the two.